# How do I change the navigationItem.title to the color white in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, firebase, uinavigationitem

How do I change the navigationItem.title to the color white in Swift 4?

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in          
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        self.navigationItem.title = dictionary["name"] as? String
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
},withCancel: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change title color using this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Comment: Value of type 'MessagesController' has no member 'navigationBar'

Comment: @JamaBarons: I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: It now builds but the text is still black

Comment: Any other suggestions? I'm honestly not sure what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
```